# ctypes and pointer manipulation

Tags: python, ctypes

I am dealing with image buffers, and I want to be able to access data a few lines into my image for analysis with a c library.  I have created my 8-bit pixel buffer in Python using create_string_buffer.  Is there a way to get a pointer to a location within that buffer without re-creating a new buffer?  My goal is to analyze and change data within that buffer in chunks, without having to do a lot of buffer creation and data copying.

In this case, ultimately, the C library is doing all the manipulation of the buffer, so I don't actually have to change values within the buffer using Python.  I just need to give my C function access to data within the buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[create_string_buffer](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.create_string_buffer) gives you a ctypes object (an array of chars), then [byref](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.byref), and I quote,

> Returns a light-weight pointer to obj,
>   which must be an instance of a ctypes
>   type. offset defaults to zero, and
>   must be an integer that will be added
>   to the internal pointer value.

The `offset` argument has been added in 2.6, so if you're stuck with an older version you will unfortunately need more work.

Comment: One thing that is a little confusing, though-- Suppose I make the following: "buff = create_string_buffer(10)". Will passing "byref(buff, 3)" pass "&(buff[3])" or "(&buff) + 3)"?

Comment: @Chris, the two expressions are equivalent -- in C, `&X[Y]==X+Y` is a tautology for any pointer X (arrays "decay to" pointers in C) and integer Y. (Here, the array's items are 1 byte each, so there can't be even any doubt about "scaling" in pointer arithmetic;-).

Comment: I realize they are equivalent in C, but I wasn't sure how ctypes would respond... in other words, would it pass the pointer incremented by 3, or a pointer to the python instance incremented by three, or something weird like that.  As usual, though, python is smart and passes the C pointer incremented by three.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI, when using `.byref()`, "The returned object can only be used as a foreign function call parameter" according to the docs

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ctypes.cast(buf, ctypes.c_void_p)`

Comment: That doesn't look like it lets me set an offset into the buffer.  Did I miss something?