# python ctypes pointer operation : can i + or - c pointer type in ctypes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, python-module

I have a dll and c code.
c code includes many functions not in dll.
and I have to make an interface(?) of these functions for python(2.7.x).
but the C code uses pointer operation,
and I don't know that in Python ctypes module.

see this(not exact code but similar):

```
void func(unsigned char *arr){
    if( *(arr-1) == *(arr+3) ) {/*...*/}
}
```

but in python ctypes module, I cannot run a code like this:

```
t = c_char_p
# .... do sth with variable t?
t -= 2;
print t.value
```

how can i make it run in python?
does any way that i can cast a c_char_p type to integer type or function for modifying the address exist?

I tried c_char_p to c_long casting but it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will want to look into [`ctypes.pointer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.pointer), [this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692185/python-how-to-increment-a-ctypes-pointer-instance), and [this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494288/ctypes-and-pointer-manipulation).